# logging the messages of queue to a text file

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have an below spring integration xml in which I send an message to queue and that message is consumed finally and displayed on console but now I want to customize it lets say those message which are consumed should be finally written (in other words those messages need to be logged)in a text file and that text file should be saved in C: drive of my folder  the name of the file is messageslog.txt

Please advise how can I add such functionality in spring integration itself to acheieve this functionality I have come to know that in spring integration something like file outbound  channel adapter will help

below is my spring integtaion xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <int:poller id="poller" default="true">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="200" />
    </int:poller>

    <int:channel id="output">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://labc.net:7033</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">wer</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">wer</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>test.data</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="input">

    </int:channel>

    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input"
        destination-name="test.data" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />

    <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        channel="output" destination-name="test.data" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change `input` to a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>`
- set `order="1"` on the jms outbound channel adapter
- subscribe a file outbound channel adapter (mode=APPEND) with `order="2"`

By default, the file adapter will be invoked only if the send to JMS is successful.

You don't seem to have a consumer on `output`; however, to avoid message loss, `output` should **NOT** be a `QueueChannel`, just remove the `<queue/>` element (and you don't need a poller).

Comment: Thanks , can you please explain a bit why input channel should be changed to publish subscribe channel and what benefit in terms of programing i would have if I set the value of  jms outbound channel adapter to order =1 . Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a pub-sub channel because there is no "reply" from the jms outbound adapter to send anywhere. Hence we use a pub/sub so both consumers (subscribers) get the message, in order. They will be invoked in the order they are declared, but I prefer explicit `order="..."` attributes to make it clear to others reading the configuration that jms is invoked first, then the file adapter.